# MAC OS / Safari position fixed (z-index? width?)

Tags: html, css, dom, safari, safari-web-inspector

this is a very specific question for a site I'm helping a friend troubleshoot. I understand if it doesn't get answered or if this question gets closed.

I was wondering if someone with a Mac and Safari could help me troubleshoot the below issue with the inspector..I'd be happy to buy you a beer next time you're in town. I'm on PC and can't replicate the problem.

This problem only occurs on Safari for Mac OS only. Chrome, Firefox, IE and other browsers display correctly.

There are a couple divs at the top, full width containing a logo and navigation.
http://912-registry.clubexpress.com

On Safari / Mac OS, my friend is saying that the big image slides on top of the navigation and underneath the logo bar at the top.

I've tried the full width 100%; position:relative; tricks as described in similar questions.

I have an idea why it's happening, because the large image is first in the DOM, the nav follows in the HTML and nav is fixed at the top with CSS. This was a kludge to avoid having to re-write the html and reorganize (which may have to be done). However, there may be a simple fix to the css hack that someone on Safari could find. 
z-index? A position relative somewhere that's missed?

Otherwise back to the drawing board.

Whaddya' say Mac guys?

Comment: Can't seem to get it to do that on OS X El Capitan and Safari 9

Comment: OS X and Safari 8.0 here. cannot replicate problem

Comment: Thanks for checking guys. I made some position:relative changes to an outer wrapper. It may have fixed it. I gave you both a vote, and owe you both a beer.